# accepting value from either of text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two asp.net textboxes and need to put a validate function in javascript or jquery to validate either one or the other should accept a value. Both can not be left blank. And it should make visible the error label if both text boxes are empty.

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: how to accept downvotes?

Comment: my question is how u do what I have described. I created a function in javascript which checks the values of the textboxes are empty and called that function in asp buttons onclientclick and also tried with forms onsumbit event. Both didn't work. Dont have the code right now.

Comment: You created the code, but don't have it...?  Erm...

Comment: well I dont have it right now...

Comment: You should always post your code in cases like that, otherwise seems like you want us to program for you.

Comment: Really. I didnt know about that. Thank you for your suggestion anyway. Hope you find a better way next time.

Comment: @helly0d what ever you think. I am sick of people who complains and cry for nothing. I guess you have a great brain. If you dont have anything just leave it out. Why you are embracing unnecessary things. Good luck to you to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javascript validation method in your head tag:

```
function chkTxt(myForm)
{
  if(myForm.txt1.value == '' && myForm.txt2.value == '')
  {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'error';
    return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}
```

You can set the `onsubmit` attribute of your form tag to call the method like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="return chkTxt(this);">
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Just a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually didnt pass the form object to the form onsubmit event. Your code works well and will check in the site tomorrow. Cheers.